# Uber rush on demand

Tags: uber-api

I'm interested in using the Uber API into my on demand delivery service, I know this service was available for Uber rush, now there is deeplink option, I would like to know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no UberRUSH API product nor a deeplink to provide deliveries for you.